# Запуск метода со ссылочным параметром в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, многопоточность, методы, ссылки

```
struct A {
    void f(int& p) {

    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    int p = 3;
    thread t(&A::f, a, p);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если убрать ссылочный тип,

```
struct A {
    void f(int p) {

    }
};
```

тогда работает

Comment: std::ref(p) надо сделать

Answer (score 1):

Всегда старайтесь оборачивать таски в std::packaged_task это даст вам фьючу !(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) перед запуском в поток!

Если у Вас референс аргумент - то так и пишите!

Перед стартом потока проверяйте его!

Перед тем как дернуть join проверяйте, а можно ли! А то будет бобо...

И всегда проверяйте как поток отработал!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

struct obj
{
    static void f(int& a) {
        ++a;
    }

};


int main() {

    std::thread th1;

    int i{100};

    std::packaged_task<void(int&)> xTask{obj::f};
    auto task{xTask.get_future()};
    std::thread th;


    if (!th1.joinable()) {
       th = std::thread{std::move(xTask), std::ref(i)};
    } else {
       th.join();
       th = std::thread{std::move(xTask), std::ref(i)};
    }

    if (th.joinable()) {
        th.join();
    }

    try {
        task.wait();
        task.get();
    } catch (std::exception& exc) {
            std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "unknown error ~ !"<< std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "i after task : " << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A {
    void f(int& p) {

    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    int p = 3;
    thread t(&A::f, a, std::ref(p));
}
```